# Onclick draggable that will follow your mouse

Tags: jquery, draggable

I have a question about the draggable function. I want to click on an element and make it draggable that will follow the mouse see: http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/drag-drop-lock.php. This demo is when you drag on the element but I want to click and it's mootools need it in Jquery please :).
Is there already a function in Jquery?

Thanks!

Frank

Comment: you mean besides jqueryui 'draggable'? did you check jquery ui plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI does have draggable interaction, see http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to